# Will my loss function work the way I would like it to work? (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

So I implemented a neural network with this code:

```py
self.model = keras.Sequential()
self.model.add(keras.Input(shape=(self.wejscia,), name="Input"))
self.model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1"))
self.model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2"))
self.model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax", name="predictions"))
```

But I wanted to make it possible to perform gradient descent on only one, chosen position of the output vector. The way i did it was like this:

First I created a class like that:

```py
class CustomMSE(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, my_output, name="custom_mse"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.my_output = my_output

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mse = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true[0,self.my_output] - y_pred[0,self.my_output]))
        return mse
```

and then I just applied compile method like that:

```py
self.model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=CustomMSE(i))
```

I am not sure of two things.

First: will the .fit method modify the wages between the second hidden layer and the j-th output for j !=i (I hope it won't)

Second: will the instruction self.model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=CustomMSE(i)) applied many times for different values of i affect the current wages of the model, or will it just change the further behavior of the network after aplying the .fit method?

Comment: What does my_output refer to? When you are creating the CustomMSE object, what is i? Also, for making custom loss functions, you need to use keras.backend functions rather than TensorFlow functions.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have, it will not work as expected, as you are using tf. functions rather than keras.backend functions to create loss functions. Here is an example of how you can create a custom loss function:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as kb
def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):
    custom_loss=kb.square(y_actual-y_pred)
    return custom_loss
```

You can use this loss function like this:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss,optimizer=optimizer)
```

Of course, this is not the same loss function you implemented, but it shows the methodology.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If i work with numpy arrays, can I index them in a usual way while while creating this loss function? For example, will a code like this work:

```

def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):
    custom_loss=kb.square(y_actual[1,2]-y_pred[1,2])
    return custom_loss

```

Comment: You should consider the fact that the batch size is included in the size of the array. Also the type of data in the function is not a numpy array, but a keras array, which in the backend is a tensorflow array.